# How do I debug XML signature mismatch

Tags: xml, soap, websphere

I am using a product called Axway API Server to add SAML Assertions to SOAP requests. The SAML Assertions are then digitally signed. I have applied a Policy Set to a JAX-WS service on WebSphere 8.5.5, which consumes these SAML assertions. (Cost me several days of my life.)

I am getting an error in WebSphere saying that there is a Digest Mismatch. (Followed, unsurprisingly by a Signature Mismatch).

There are a limited number of configuration options on either side, and I've tried what I believe are all the combinations, but no joy.

So, has anyone any idea how I might proceed to get to the bottom of this ?

Answer (score 1):

Extract the SAML assertion from the SOAP request and validate it using another product/tool outside of WebSphere. Make sure to extract it as raw bytes (or base64-encoded) or the entire exercise will be null and void.

I use OpenSAML for dealing with any low-level SAML issues. It has a learning curve but it's probably your best option: https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OpenSAML/Home

Comment: Thanks for that. Can you elaborate on "extract it as raw bytes" ?

Comment: XML signature is over a byte stream so you want raw, unparsed bytes as the input to your test with another tool. As opposed to taking the parsed SAML assertion (as XML segment/document) from some log file.